# How to Run Powershell script in private windows machine from client machine through bastion

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-server, rdp, winrm

**I have 3 windows machines**

**Machine A:**    Bastion

**Machine B:**    Private machine

**Machine C:**    Local/Client Machine

Now,

I have a script in Bastion server which has the code to connect to Private machine through Powershell PS-Session and execute few commands in Private machine. Which is working fine.

But, if i do Powershell PS-Session from my local machine to Bastion and run the same script (The script has commands to connect to Private machine)getting below error.

Instead of connecting to bastion and run commands in private machine, I want to directly connect to the private machine from my local client machine through bastion.

### Error:

Enter-PSSession : You are currently in a Windows PowerShell PSSession and cannot use the Enter-PSSession cmdlet to
enter another PSSession.
At C:\Users\Administrator\tst.ps1:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName ##### -Credential Administrato ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Enter-PSSession], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoteHostDoesNotSupportPushRunspace,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.EnterPSSessionCommand